# How do I make queries made by JDBC show up in postgres logs?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

[image]I am working on a spring boot server using Postgres as the database. I would like to be able to have a log file of the queries coming from the server. I have found my sql logs and I can see queries I make to the database via psql but queries coming from my server via jdbc are not logged. How can I get these queries to show in my log file? Or if they are just being logged somewhere else could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Queries logged to Postgres' logs are not differentiated by application--can you update your post with your values for `log_min_duration_statement` and `log_statement` in your `SHOW ALL` output (run `SHOW ALL` from `psql`).  Please also show the other params related to `log_*`

Comment: I added a picture with the log values

Comment: Why you just don't log SQL calls in Spring Boot application logs? like: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`

Comment: I am already doing that. The problem is a certain query is not returning a result set but it works when I copy paste it from the server log to psql. I want to be able to see the logs postgres is putting out to see what's going on from the database side.

Answer (score 0):

You can set log_min_duration_statement to 0 to log all statements.  Be careful, though, as this can greatly increase the size of your logs.

It's also helpful to set the application name in the jdbc connection url so it's easier to pick out the appropriate log messages:

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/DB?ApplicationName=YourApp
```

Answer (score 0):

If `log_statement=all` is coming from your postgresql.conf file, but it doesn't seem to be effective sometimes, then it is possible that that setting has been overridden at the database or user level.  Make sure you are connected to the same database and as the same user as your app server connects, before you issue the 'SHOW ALL'.

They could have been overridden by something like one of these:

```
alter user <foo> set log_statement='none';
alter database <foo> set log_statement='none';
```

However, to ensure users can't hide their activity from the superuser, only a superuser would have been allowed to issue one of the above.  And if your app logs in as a superuser (not a good idea), then it could have turned off logging at the session level, overriding the conf file.

If it is one of the above commands which changed the setting, you can see it with \drds in psql, or in SQL with:

```
SELECT rolname AS "Role", datname AS "Database",
pg_catalog.array_to_string(setconfig, E'\n') AS "Settings"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting s
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database d ON d.oid = setdatabase
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles r ON r.oid = setrole
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: If I run `show all` from intellij using the postgres console I can see the log level is set to something different from my postgresql.conf. Any idea where I could find the configuration that's being used when a jdbc connects?

Comment: Configuration key is called 'log_statement' not 'log_statements'

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the logs of every query, I use the option `log_statement=all` which is configured as a command line argument, for the process of postgres. I use the following docker compose file in order to run the postgresql database in development environment.

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  db-ct:
    container_name: 'my-container-name'
    image: 'postgres:13'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=database-username-created-on-container-creation
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=database-password-created-on-container-creation
      - POSTGRES_DB=database-name-created-on-container-creation
    ports:
      # The port is available by sql clients, like sqldeveloper
      - '5000:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    restart: 'no'
    # Run postgres and log all queries
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all" ]
    networks:
      internal:

volumes:
  # Database files
  # They are stored in a volume thus they are not reset after rebuilding the images
  db:
    name: your-volume-name

networks:
  internal:
```

Line 19: The command line argument

4 replaces are required: `my-container-name`, `database-username-created-on-container-creation`, `database-password-created-on-container-creation`, `database-name-created-on-container-creation`, `your-volume-name`

The database will listen on port 5000.